# Swift Struct extension

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I have a Settings struct that stores hundreds of settings in `UserDefaults`. 
Code below:

```
struct Settings {

public enum key: String
{
    case mySetting = "mySetting"
    ...
    ...

}

 public var mySetting: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: key.mySetting.rawValue)
    }

    set (newValue) {
        return UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key.mySetting.rawValue)
    }
}

 ....
 ....
}
```

I want to extend it. I want to fetch settings of another instance of the app running on a peer device and store it as a `Dictionary`. `mySetting` must them return the value of a key.mySetting `key` from that `dictionary` rather than `UserDefaults`. But if there is no peer device connected, then it should return the value in `UserDefaults`.

I am wondering how I can extend the Settings struct (or perhaps change it to class if needed) to achieve this functionality without putting 'if then else' in hundreds of places in the code.

I do this in hundreds of place:

```
 var settings = Settings()
```

Or

```
 let settings = Settings()
```

Some construct that automatically pulls the right settings dictionary to look for would be best.

Edit: As I said not all return types can be simple which makes the job harder. Some return types are enum, some dictionary, some Array. As some suggest to have one unified method that returns Any?, the job would be harder at places where I use the return type, for instance.

```
  public var microphone: Microphone {
    get {
        if let mic = Microphone.init(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: key.microphone.rawValue)) {
            return mic
        } else {
            return .auto
        }
    }

    set (newValue) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: key.microphone.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add to code your Settings struct?

Comment: The code was of Settings only, I just updated it.

Comment: The problem with your code is that each setting in defaults passes through a different method; for example, `public var mySetting` deals only with the `mySetting` defaults key. You should be passing everything through _one_ method.

Comment: @matt the problem is not all setting vars/methods have same return type. Some return types are enums and I do the hard-work in those methods. How can just one method take care of everything? If I have a method that returns Any?, then in the places where I use the method, I will need to redo the hardwork. Example above (code edited).

Comment: That is why generics exist.

Comment: How do generics make life easier in this case, I would love to here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add an optinal property for the dictionary and then using a pair of get and set functions either use the dictionary or UserDefaults

```
var peerDevice: [String: Any]?

func setting(forKey key: Key) -> Any? {
    if let dictionary = peerDevice {
        return dictionary[key.rawValue]
    }
    return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key.rawValue)
}

mutating func set(_ value: Any, forKey key: Key) {
    if peerDevice != nil {
        peerDevice?[key.rawValue] = value
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
    }        
}
```

Example of wrapper method for enums using raw values

```
mutating func setEnum<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key) where T: RawRepresentable {
    set(value.rawValue, forKey: key)
}

func setting<T>(forKey key: Key, andEnumType: T.Type) -> T? where T: RawRepresentable {
    if let value = setting(forKey: key) as? T.RawValue {
        return T.init(rawValue: value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I took the liberty to rename the enum from `key` to `Key`

Then use it like this

```
var settings = Settings()

settings.setSetting(true, forKey: .mySetting)

if let flag = settings.setting(forKey: .mySetting) as? Bool {
    print(flag)
}

settings.setEnum(Microphone.mic2, forKey: .mic)

if let mic = settings.setting(forKey: .mic, andEnumType: Microphone.self) {
    print(mic)
}
```

Comment: I edited the code, let me know how to take care of all possible return types in settings. May be I am missing something, but will this code still work seemlessly in case you have complex return types such as enums?

Comment: @DeepakSharma See the first methods as base methods for getting and setting values, then you can add wrapper methods to use for different types. I add one for enums to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a quick question, have the settings as a struct vs class, since there would be too many methods, does it make sense to have Settings as a class than a struct?

Comment: It doesn’t really matter, I would probably use a struct. Since you only want, at least I assume so, one instance of the Setting object you should consider making it into a Singleton.

Comment: And I have other types too -- Array, Dictionary, Float64?, Float?, Int?..easy to accommodate all of them with Generics? (sorry, I am not comfortable with syntax of Generics and the right usage, still learning)

Comment: what I mean is I use Userdefaults.standard.array(..), Userdefaults.standard.integer(...). Their behavior is not always consistent with Userdefaults.standard.value...Userdefaults.standard.integer will yield 0 when value is nil for instance.

Comment: @DeepakSharma For most types you should be able to use my base functions that uses `Any`, maybe this will not work for collections like Array and Dictionary but you should not have to implement that many extra functions

Comment: Why Any wouldn't work for Array & Dictionary, I am curious?

Comment: Why not try yourself and see if it does?

Comment: It actually compiles using optional binding "as? Array<[String:Any?]>". Need to check if it works but that would take some time before I update whole code.